# bash: how to apply multiple commands to same file and concatenate outputs

Tags: bash, awk

Let's say that I want to aggregate the values by column on a tab separated file and preserve the header.

I could do:

```
  (head -n 1 <infile> && tail -n +2 | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}' <infile>) > <outfile>
```

But let's say that I want the input to be coming from a pipe (e.g. I am doing the operation on a specific column).

How can I do that?

Does the one liner below work?

```
  (head -n 1 && tail -n +2 | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}') <infile>  > <outfile>
```

If I want to sum just the k-th column, would the following work?

```
  cut -f<k> <infile> | (head -n 1 && tail -n +2 | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}')  > <outfile>
```

How are these statements interpreted by bash?

Comment: Your first attempt would almost work on a pipe (once you remove `<infile>` which is just an error there). That being said you don't want to bother involving `head` or `tail` here at all, just do it all with `awk` directly (use `NR` to do different operations based on the current line number, etc.).

Comment: Post some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 3):

Do it all in `awk`, by testing `NR`

```
somecommand | awk 'NR == 1 { print; next } { s += $1 } END { print s }' > outfile
```

This prints the first line normally because of `NR == 1`, and then sums up the first column in the remaining lines.